# Adding a Delete (or Mass Delete) button to Lead List View

Tags: custom-button

I'm new around here, and have been tasked with doing some configuration on our new SF Lightning deployment prior to rolling it out to our other users.

I have a few questions the need answers, but this is hopefully an easy on to get started with.

From the Leads List view (Table), how can I Delete (or preferably mass delete by selecting more than one item), via a button in the top section?

I went to Setup > Object Mgr > Lead > Search Layout > List View but Delete / MassDelete is not an option in the Standard buttons.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Actually, on the same topic, the Accept option does not seem to display either. Pretty sure it was there, but I must have removed it somehow. I am clearly very new to this. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

"Accept" only appears on list views that filter by a specific Queue, and only for those users that would be able to accept the lead. Notably, this means that Recently Viewed, etc won't have this button. The related [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194204&type=1) states:

> By design, The Accept button is present only when a List consists of records that are still in queue and not assigned to any specific owner.
>
> Also. if the List View has mix of Leads assigned and Leads in queue the Accept button will still not be available.
>
> Note: This works similarly to the Cases List View where the Accept button is available only when the List View consist of records that are still in queue.

You might need to use the drop down to see the Accept button:

[image: Accept Button in overflow menu]

"Mass Delete" is not a standard feature in Salesforce. You would need to write a custom list action. Here's [one](https://dandonin.com/2017/10/12/mass-delete-list-view-button-in-lightning/) that I found just with a quick search on the Internet (not my blog/post/code). You can find others out there too, lots of people have done this.

Comment: The Lead list i'm is (and all others that I checked) have the same action button options at the upper right, and are queues from which our users normally Accept leads. I am sure the Accept (and the single Delete) options were there, but now are not. As I said, I suspect I've done something that has removed them by mistake.

I looked at the Mass Delete option you linked and was unable to install the suggested package do to Missing Apex Classes.

Comment: @ChrisI The accept button is toggled on/off in Leads > Search Layouts > List Views. Also added documentation on when it will (or will not) appear. The mass delete app was just a demo, you'll find to find one that works for you, or write your own. It's really a trivial amount of code, and you can ask for assistance if you get stuck, but we the community ask that you make a solid attempt at it first. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_massupdate.htm) should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for adding that additional information regarding the different list view scenarios. I can confirm that the Accept Button is not present on any of the lists that previously had them. 

According to Object Manager > Lead > Search Layouts, the List View layout should show New, Accept, Change Status, Change Owner, Accept, Change Status, Change Owner. When I go to edit that list, those are the items that are ticked.  When I view the List View page(s) of various queues I see the options for New, Import, Change Status and Change Owner.

Comment: I'll have one of our devs help me with the Mass Delete Code. Thanks for the link and the advice on that front.

Comment: @ChrisI I just tested the Accept button, it does indeed work. Check your list view filters, or maybe get in contact with support. It definitely *should* be there.

Comment: @ChrisI Also, added a screenshot of where it might be.

Comment: Yep, that's where it should be, and it's ticked in the appropriate Search Layout screen, but doesn't appear in Leads, regardless of the view. I've tried enabling and disabling other options in that list, and they appear and disappear as they are supposed to. Just not the Accept option. Guess I might need to contact SF Support.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris

I know I'm late to comment here. We use Lightning, and when I downloaded the Mass Delete app/components, I had to add the button to the Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic instead of Search Layouts to get it to appear in the List View..[image: Mass_Delete_Search_Results]